# Table row is getting cut while using wkhtmltopdf node module converting to pdf

Tags: html, css, node.js, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltopdf-binary

Facing issue while converting HTML to PDF long one almost 3-4 pages of tables data is available. Its getting cut and distorted.

I tried most of solution which is mention related to wkhtmltopdf stackoverflow thread.[image]

```
table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
```

this doesnt help me

Any help in this ?

Comment: And what's the goal, to break on table row? Seems like your css is wrong, you specified not to break the page anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `tr {page-break-inside: avoid; }`? Also make sure you use [latest wkhtmltopdf library](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html).

Comment: i tried this also its not worked @skobaljic

Comment: its getting cut half-half. I have to solve that issue.

Comment: Yeah... seems like they still haven't solved it, check [this](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3195) and [that](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2141)... Maybe best to divide your table before printing/converting?

Comment: @skobaljic this solve issue see the answer.

Comment: Great, you can see I googled 30 minutes and I saw all those issues, for which people said they were solved... and at the end you tell us you used old version lols :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading wkhtmltopdf to version 0.12.5 with qt patched resolved my issue.

[Script to install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 with qt patched on ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/Rajeshr34/2e9b2438ff142e51c729b4b9b772680a)

If you face any issues related to zooming and extra whitespace try add these options in the
[wkhtmltopdf npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf)

```
--zoom  value between 0.0 to 1.0

--disable-smart-shrinking
```

Issues related to this from GitHub :
[Regression on upgrade from 0.12.3 to 0.12.5](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4528)